# javascript html5 localstorage messes up the code

Tags: html, local-storage

I'm using this piece of code for my image slider...

> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> ```
>   $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
>     jsonPath : 'json/customData.json',
>     jsonSuccess : customDataSuccess,
>     lazyLoad : true
>   });
>
>   function customDataSuccess(data){
>     var content = "";
>     for(var i in data["items"]){
>
>        var img = data["items"][i].img;
>        var alt = data["items"][i].alt;
>        var myclass = data["items"][i].class;
>        var link = data["items"][i].link;
>      localStorage.setItem("imga", img);
>      localStorage.setItem("alta", alt);
>      localStorage.setItem("linka", link);
>        content += "<a href=\""+link+"\"><img data-src=\"" +img+ "\" alt=\"" +alt+ "\" class=\"" +myclass+ "\"></a>"
>     }
>     $("#owl-demo").html(content);
>   }
>
>
> });
> ```

as soon I insert the localStorage element the script doesnt work anymore (the slider doesnt appear)...  what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: You getting any errors?

Comment: What browser are you testing? Have you confirmed that your browser actually supports the localStorage feature?

Comment: where;s the code for using stored data? Flaw in your `setItem` code...you overwrite the same storage key every pass of `for` loop

Comment: I'm testing with IE8 and firefox 23  ... i hope they support localstorage ???   and I'm not getting errors

Comment: ok now I'm sure the localstore is suported ... I used the code outside the loop...
localStorage.setItem("imga", img);
        $("#owl-demo").html(content);
      }
the firebug in firefox shows the data is stored...

but now i dont know how to store the specific values :(

Comment: Why are you adding it to localstorage?  All you are doing is building up a set of anchor tags with img innerhtml from the data passed from the json.  Just remove the localstorage.setItem as you had previously.  Also, see if the a href html is correctly formed in the source?  If you want to increase performance you should be caching the images...

Comment: couse i need the data on another webpage to work with ... if i click on 1 item it needs to transfer the item date to another page to display them ...

Comment: Just stored the data variable in localstorage outside of the loop?  As @charlietfl mentioned above your setItem is overwriting the previous value in the loop.

Comment: Yes now I know it overwrites the previous value... i put the code outside the loop just to check if the browser actually works with the localstorage. The main problem now is how to send data of the item to another page when i click on it

Comment: there is no `send to another page`...it's in local data regardless of the page you are on. Again...where's the code you use to retrieve and compile data from localStorage?

Comment: I'm going to update my answer below - it won't be tried and tested - just an idea of how you would go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local Storage is supported in modern browsers.

If you are testing in Internet Explorer 7 or below it will not work.

Check [HTML5 Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_webstorage.asp) for supported browsers.

I suggest looking at Modernizr to detect what features the browser supports and act accordingly.  What I've done in the past is use localstorage if it's supported and fall back to using a cookie if it's not.  [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/)

UPDATE

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    jsonPath: 'json/customData.json',
    jsonSuccess: customDataSuccess,
    lazyLoad: true
});

function customDataSuccess(data) {
    var content = "";
    for (var i in data["items"]) {

        var img = data["items"][i].img;
        var alt = data["items"][i].alt;
        var myclass = data["items"][i].class;
        var link = data["items"][i].link;
        localStorage.setItem("imga" + i, img);
        localStorage.setItem("alta" + i, alt);
        localStorage.setItem("linka" + i, link);
        content += "<a href=\"" + link + "?id=" + i + "\"><img data-src=\"" + img + "\" alt=\"" + alt + "\" class=\"" + myclass + "\"></a>"
    }
    $("#owl-demo").html(content);
}
```

});

So now the localstorage items will be in there individually, then what you will need to do on the new page is look up the items from localstorage with the id that's been passed via the querystring in the url.

The function on the new page that gets the id from the querystring then looks up the values in the localstorage could be something like this:

```
function getLocalStorageItem(id) {

   var img = localStorage.getItem("imga" + id);
   var alt = localStorage.getItem("alta" + id);
   var link = localStorage.getItem("linka" + id);
```

}

You will need to write the code to get the querystring value for the id parameter then pass that into the getLocalStorageItem function.

Obviously, this is a quick way - you will need to optimise this.

Comment: both browsers are compatible with localstorage

Comment: That being said, you should probably get into the habit of testing whether the browser supports it via modernizr.  It's good practice.  @LitBe

Comment: yes the solutions is great thank you!  now i just have to solve the problem  with the url query string ... i tried a few of them ... but doesnt seem to work ...